# Error launching React Native app from command line

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app and recently upgraded to React Native 0.55. I previously could run the command `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"` to launch the app in the Simulator. Now I cannot, but I can still run the app in Xcode using build and run.

Here is the error from the `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"` output:

```
▸ Compiling RCTBundleURLProvider.m

❌  /dev/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBundleURLProvider.m:15:53: use of undeclared identifier 'undefined'; did you mean 'underline'?

const NSUInteger kRCTBundleURLProviderDefaultPort = RCT_METRO_PORT;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling RCTLayoutAnimationGroup.m
▸ Compiling RCTNavigator.m
▸ Compiling RCTTabBar.m
** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /dev/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTBundleURLProvider.o Base/RCTBundleURLProvider.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

In case it helps, here's the output of `react-native info`:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
  Node: 9.5.0
  Yarn: 1.3.2
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.3.0-alpha.1 => 16.3.0-alpha.3
  react-native: 0.55.0 => 0.55.0
```

What's wrong with my setup and how should I fix it?

Comment: Try running npm i -g react-native-cli

Comment: @locropulenton same behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you should try
`react-native run-ios --port 8088` or `RCT_METRO_PORT=8081 react-native run-ios` but unsure if that works.

`RCT_METRO_PORT` var was added in commit [33d710e8c58ef1dc69816a59ac1cf390894e7cb9](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/33d710e8c58ef1dc69816a59ac1cf390894e7cb9#diff-0822d6820d37285597b7a89988c8aea1) and looks like it breaks versions 0.54/0.55 to run ios apps from the cli.

In the meantime I continue using xcode to run my react-native apps.

Hopefully it can be patched or cherry picked or ultimately be fixed on the next major release.

There is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18525) about it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.